# Monitoring script started by rc.local

Tags: centos, monitoring, c

We have a C program which is started using `rc.local`´. We added a line like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/pc
```

to the `rc.local` file. `pc` is a compiled C program. Everything is working fine at the moment. What we are worrying about is `pc` crashing. If it does, is there any way to monitor that and restart the program automatically?

Comment: Your monitoring program would need to know about which instance to monitor. It is probably simpler to just start a monitoring program and have that configured to start our `/usr/local/bin/pc` and keep it running. This is most often done by watching if the known PID of the started program is still active. There seems to be no standard for this and multiple home-brew solutions exist, e.g. [mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/) comes with `procer` which works quite nice.

Comment: You use something like `supervisord` to start the process and restart it if it dies.

Comment: @Anthon how about monit is it good for this purpose? But how to make it start the C programme I am not too sure with it?

Comment: @biz14 From the website blurb `monit` looks ok, but I have not used it. You can tell it where to look for the PID in a file, so you have to make sure your program writes it if it doesn't already.

Comment: @Anthon so my programme must write the PID is it possible for a process to write to any location?

Comment: @biz14 I would write the PID in a file `/var/run/pc` that is a temporary file system on my machine, so it is cleared on reboot. I took a second look at monit this morning, but IMHO it tries to do a bit too much.

Comment: @Anthon when you say you will write means I can just create a file  /var/run/pc and write the PID in it once it had started right? So why do you say that monit tried to do a bit too much what is the too much? So in case my app crash how am I going to update the /var/run/pc file?

Comment: @biz14 monit also does all kind of other things in addition to monitoring and restarting (TCP/IP network check, protocol check, HTTP) interface. The more complex the controlling program, the higher the chance of that getting into trouble itself.

Comment: @biz14 you write the PID on startup, assuming you only want a single instance of the `pc` program (if not you need a more complex scheme). On crash the monitoring program notices the process with PID in the file is no longer there, and restarts it (and waits a little bit to give the program the time to write the PID). The monitoring program could remove `/var/run/pc` but the program could overwrite it once started (optionally checking if it was already started based on the old contents to prevent double instances of itself). A monitoring program for a single program does not need to be complex

Comment: @Anthon I am sorry I am new to all this but I notice monit is able to even email the user incase of crash which I think a good feature though? So based on your idea yes I want only a single instance of the pc programme to be running. What are the exact steps I should do now? What monitoring program is your recommendation since you have better experience.

Comment: @biz14 I am only *suspicious* of the extra capabilities `monit` provides, but it is probably more important for you to get something with all the features you need. Try it out, and monitor yourself that `monit` keeps running. Make sure to actively test that `monit` works by killing your pc program and make sure it restarts and you get the email that you want.

Comment: @Anthon what is your opinion about the /etc/inittab method? I think I will give that a trial first and then back to this monit as I am not too sure it need a pid file which now I guess you have told me where to put.What should be the content of the file?

Comment: The /etc/inittab seems good. I had actually forgotten about being able to do that since not running serial ports any more (last UUCP was in 1997). But like you indicated it will not notify you of restarts. You could however have `pc` notify you on startup, via email or some other way, would that not help? I think an extra email on reboot can be lived with.

Comment: @Anthon ok good idea let me see how to have C to email me never tried before but will learn too.

Comment: I added a quick-and-dirty way to get an email from C as an addition to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `rc.local` you are probably using some sysV init as well? You could add a line

```
pc:2345:respawn:/usr/local/bin/pc
```

to `/etc/inittab`. This line means the program will be started for the runlevels 2,3,4 and 5 and will automatically be restarted when it terminates, i.e. crashes.

Comment: In this case I dont need any monitoring tool is it? Once I put this line I will need to reboot to put it in effect?

Comment: @biz14 you can also just use `init q` or `telinit q`

Comment: @biz14: correct on the monitoring. `init` does that for you, as long as you don't care about details on the crash. As Ulrich points out, you don't need to reboot.

Comment: @user1129682 if I need to care about the crash details then should I use the /etc/inittab. How will it know when my process is death it will keep an eye on the process is it?

Comment: `init` does what Anthon wrote as a comment to your question. it spawns a process and watches it. if the process is destroyed for whatever reason it is respawened. That's what `respawn` means in the inittab file. If you need to take special actions after the program crashes you need another program which does takes the special actions, but you haven't told us about those yet.

Comment: @user1129682 ok my first step I think I will first edit the /etc/inittab and add this line pc:2345:respawn:/usr/local/bin/pc. So will this respawn if my process crashed. Sorry for my misinformation yes I need the special action to look for why the crash happened and if there is any bug to look for it. How is this possible then?

Comment: That depends on the errors you are looking for. Apparently you are not seeking to have a service run, no matter what, but you are trying to debug an application that's still under development. Testing and debugging are a little beyond the scope of what I can help you with free of context.

Comment: @user1129682 apparently the service is running well no issue. Just that when the db goes down then I notice this service stop to work as it have errors. So this is the main issue I am worries and would like to respawn it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `rc.local` as suggested by user1129682 seems a good idea. If you want a quick (and dirty) way to see if your program (re-) started you can change your program to email you as it starts up. To do so install the `mailutils` package and have your C program start like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   system("echo | mail -s \"pc started\" your@email.addr");
   return orginal_main(argc, argv);
}
```

this assumes that the machine `pc` is running on has email forwarding properly functioning.

Comment: thank you a lot of the codes but I guess is best I will put in the main function itself to be the first line rather then calling it separately?

Comment: Essentially you only need the `system()` line and the possible the include of `stdlib.h` if you do not already have that one in your source. Putting that line in your existing main is fine. (And make sure to fill in an appropriate email address). I just made a complete test program before posting that originally return 0 and adapted that return line.

Comment: thank you a lot and give me some time try out all the different possible solution. Appreciate all your knowledge and time.